# Docker container not able to reach another container url from config file

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm very new to docker concepts, i have few node microservices, i have created docker images for them using Dockerfile, i have run these images on docker containers using docker run command, now i'm testing these node apis using postman. one of the microservice named inventory has another microservice named sopra's url in its config file to run it properly. when i'm trying to test in postman it's giving status: 500 internal server error. but when it is running locally using npm start then postman is giving message success. i have created a seperate docker network named test and created these 2 containers in that test network.

to create a new network i have used `docker network create test`
then to run those containers in that network i have used
`docker run -dp 1050:5006 --name inventory-container --net=test inventory-image` &
`docker run -dp 925:5008 --name sopra-container --net=test sopra-image`

and i even checked if they both can communicate with each other using ping command

to get the ip address of the container i have used
`docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.[network].IPAddress}}' inventory-container` and i got ip as 172.21.0.2

next i used `docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.test.IPAddress}}' sopra-container` and i got ip as 172.21.0.3

now to check the ping i have used  `docker exec inventory-container ping 172.21.0.3 -c2` & `docker exec sopra-container ping 172.21.0.2 -c2` and both are returning 2 packs transmitted , 0% packet loss

sopra container is working fine as it is giving success message and oauth token is generated and inventory container is also working fine as i have tested it's api when it doesn't require sopra token it also givng success message but only when need to connect to sopra it's giving error as internal server error.

this is my config.env file inside inventory-image

```
SOPRA_SERVICE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:925/api/v1
ENVIRONMENT_NAME='Dev'
DATE_FORMAT_TIME_ZONE='America/Indiana/Indianapolis'
```

Comment: localhost will never work. use the container name as hostname instead of an IP. its the idiomatic way of doing it. You should rarely need to fetch the actual IPs inside the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container has its own `localhost` so connecting to `localhost` would try to connect to a service running within the container and as you don't have the *sopra* service running within the container on `localhost` you can't connect to it.

Also don't use hardcoded IPs. Docker supports service discovery in user-defined network bridges such as your `test` network. You can just use the container name instead of the IP address to connect to the container.

Here an excerpt from the [Docker networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks):

> On user-defined networks like alpine-net, containers can not only communicate by IP address, but can also resolve a container name to an IP address. This capability is called automatic service discovery.

You also need to be careful with port mappings.

```sh
docker run -p <host-port>:<container-port> <some-image>
```

The first port is the port on the `host`, the second port the one on the container. So if you want to connect from the outside to one of your services e.g. using Postman use the first port. If you want to connect to the service from within your `test` network, use the container port.

Applying all three, change `SOPRA_SERVICE_BASE_URL` in `config.env` and it should work:

```
SOPRA_SERVICE_BASE_URL=http://sopra-container:5008/api/v1
```

For an easier setup of your microservices (especially if there are more than two) I would recommend [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

Comment: i have changed the url as suggested and again created docker image and run the container but it's still giving same error and to double check i have opened cli of inventory-container and used cat config.env it's showing new url as updated, but postman still giving error

Comment: Postman is on the host machine and **not** within the user-defined network. You can only use the container name to connect to the container when your within that network. Maybe I don't understand the issue. I thought the problem was that one container *inventory* could not connect to the *sopra* container? Or is the problem that you cannot connect to the *sopra* container using Postman?

Comment: Just noticed you are using the host port to connect to *sopra*. `925` is the port opened on the host so you need to use that when using Postman, but for a service within the Docker network you need to use the container port which is defined as `5008`.

Comment: do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/72010307/18877380