# "The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used." when node js app deployed to azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created azure app service and deployed node js app into it through Filezilla by connecting through FTP. but when i test it in postman using "`post`" method with url "https://nextgen-stormleads3.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/auth/login".

it's giving error as `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

other than my node files i have included a web.config file in the app service with following code

```
https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/8ad0d30ac1b1aa3d0334
```

can anyone suggest what iam doing wrong here?

[i have added your suggested code in web.config still no change same error as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Fqu.png)

Comment: With FTP, web.config will not be hosted in Azure Web App.Make sure web.config is deployed in KUDU console.

Comment: i have checked through kudu console i can see web.config file there just for double check deleted the existing and again put in web.config file, and i have changed my web.config file to this "https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/8ad0d30ac1b1aa3d0334"

Comment: now when i test through postman get status:500 internal server error

Comment: Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827821/http-500-when-testing-bot-deployed-to-azure)

Comment: Add the node version to package.json

Comment: i added the node version still it's giving same error, i'm wondering do we need to change anything web.config because in local host app is working fine

Comment: Is `web.config` is under `wwwroot` folder ?It has to be in root directory `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: yes it is under root folder

Comment: Enable CORS in web.config

Comment: Add `<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

Comment: please see the image above added suggested changes in web.config under system.webserver still no change in error